# Some portions of code in batch files are not executing

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem in this batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%l in (input1.txt) do (
    ping %%l> "Result.txt"

    set "var=HI"
    set "var1=hi"
    set "var2=1";

   FIND /c "Destination host unreachable." Result.txt && ( set "var2=2") || ( echo HI)
   FIND /c "Request timed out." Result.txt && ( set "var2=2" ) || (echo HI)

   if "!var2!" EQU "2" (echo %%l>>"failure.txt")

    # This block doesn't work
    if "!var2!" EQU "1" (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (Result.txt) do ( set var=%%i)
        for /f "tokens=9" %%j in ("%var%") do (set var1=%%j)
        set var1="!var1:~0,-2!"
        if "!var1!" LSS "1000" (echo %%l >> "success.txt") ELSE (echo %%l >>"timeout.txt")
    )
)
endlocal
```

The above code is designed for ping bulk list of servers and redirect the servers to successful or failure text files based on the test results. Here the problem is the code marked by a `rem` remark is not working. It seems that portion is not executed. Also var1 is not being evaluated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you success or failure.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (input1.txt) do (
  ping %%l >nul
  if errorlevel 1 (
        >>"failure.txt" echo %%l
     ) else (
        >>"success.txt" echo %%l
  )
)
```

A problem in your code is that you are forcing string compares by using quotes around `"!var1!"` and the numeral.

You also have two sets of quotes around `!var1!`